# Best database table design for a table with dependent column values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I would like know the best way of designing a table structure for dependent column values.

If i have a scenario like this this

[image: dbstructure]

1. if the status of the field is alive nothing to do
2. if the status is died some other column values are stored somehow.

What is the best way to handle this situation

1. whether to create table containing all columns ie 'Died in the hospital','Cause of death','Date of Death' and 'Please narrate the event' and let it be null when status is alive

or

2. to use seperate table for storing all the other attributes using Entity-attribute-value (EVA) concepts

[image: dbstructure]

in the above scenario signs and symptoms may be single, multiple or others with specification. how to store this .
 what is the best way for performance and querying 
  either to provide 15 columns in single table and store null if no value or to store  foreign key of symptoms in another table (in this strategy how to store other symptom description column).

Comment: You could do a table containing all the data. Or, you could have your main table and a column for DIED that contains a foreign key to a table of death details, and if patient is alive you just leave the DIED empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if you know what the columns are, you should  include those  in the table.  So, a table with columns such as: `died_in_hospital`, `cause_of_death`, and so on seems like a reasonable solution.

Entity-attribute-value models are useful under two circumstances:

1. The attributes are not known and new ones are added over time.
2. The number of attributes is so large and sparsely populated that most columns would be `NULL`.

In your case, you know the attributes, so you should put them into a table as columns.

Comment: kindly help for the last portion of the edited question

Answer (score 1):

Entity-attribute-value models is the best method, it will be helpful in data filtering/searching. Keeping the columns in the base table itself is against Normalization rules.